# FBAudience Network : _GADFBAdSizeFromAdSize in libAdapterFacebook.a(GADFBBannerAd.o)

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-audience-network

Recently updated facebook sdk "v4.14.0 - July 13, 2016" and my project is not getting compiled, facing the below issue. Is it some issue with the sdk or something else ?

```
(null): _GADFBAdSizeFromAdSize in libAdapterFacebook.a(GADFBBannerAd.o)
(null): Symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, take a look here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/xlytZPullto

or just download libAdapterFacebook.a here:
https://dl.google.com/dl/googleadmobadssdk/libadapterfacebook.zip